# Unity3D changing AnimationClip with AnimatorOverrideController on runtime doesn't work

Tags: unity-game-engine, animator

I'm using Unity3D 2019.3 version. I have the following code and I think it worked on previous versions but it doesn't work in this version.

```
var animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
var aoc = new AnimatorOverrideController(animator.runtimeAnimatorController);
animator.runtimeAnimatorController = aoc;
aoc["StateName"] = newAnimationClip;
```

Comment: Could you please explain what is not working in detail?

Comment: Create the OverrideController in Editor, follow this guide: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimatorOverrideController.html

Comment: @HasanEmrahSüngü I knew what is problem. I thought string in AnimatorOverrideController.this[string] means the name of state in Animator. But it actually means the name of AnimationClip. Is any way to use state name or tag on state?